# Selenium get http response headers or access the browsers's download history

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use python 2.7 and the selenium driver as downloaded from

```
pip install selenium
```

How can I get the http headers from a web request.

In particular I click a button/link and the server replies with a response
containing a csv file.

It would be  awesome if I could get the filename from the http headers.

Another option would e to access the browser's download history.

Any ideas how the above can be achieved?

Comment: Any particular reason you want to do this? Are you trying to verify the web is making a correct API call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selenium can't actually do this (capture network traffic). I would suggest using a third party tool like [Browser Mob](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy)

I don't know if you can get your browser's download history... but as a workaround you can just [download files](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/faq.html) to an empty directory, and just call that your download history. You could also rank files by time downloaded using `os.path.getmtime`

```
import os

from selenium import webdriver

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "/tmp/empty-dir")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/octet-stream")

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
browser.get("http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium")
browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text("selenium-2").click()

os.listdir("/tmp/empty-dir")
['selenium-2.44.0.tar.gz']
```

Comment: Is getting the download history possible?

Comment: I can't find any reference to the download history in the [source](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/) or the [docs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/faq.html). That doesn't mean you couldn't do it; but it probably isnt trivial